# How to get rif of GPU hangups?

Tags: gpu

My Ubuntu os shows always GPU hangup i dont know to slove this???

Can anybody help me??

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 OS.

My computer configuration is I5 and 4GB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

change:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""quiet splash i915.lvds_downclock=1 drm.vblankoffdelay=1  i915.semaphores=1"
```

and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

[Is there a power saving application similar to Jupiter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/jupiter-or-similar-power-saving-app-for-13-04/285681#285681)